# Why doesn't boost circular_buffer store my booleans?

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

This simple piece of code adds 2 `bool`s to a circular buffer.

```
boost::circular_buffer<bool> stuff;
stuff.push_back(false);
stuff.push_back(true);
cout << stuff.size() << endl; // prints 0
```

Unfortunately, seems no objects are added and the `size()` is zero. Can someone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 4):

You don't set the capacity of the `circular_buffer`.

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html#idp9046288-bb)

> Now the constructor does not allocate any memory and both capacity and size are set to zero. Also note when inserting an element into a circular_buffer with zero capacity (e.g. by push_back(const_reference) or insert(iterator, value_type)) nothing will be inserted and the size (as well as capacity) remains zero.

Hence, you should construct the buffer as such:

```
size_t const BUFFER_CAPACITY(1024); // Whatever is appropriate
boost::circular_buffer<bool> stuff(BUFFER_CAPACITY);
```

An alternative is to use the [`set_capacity(...)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html#idp8376080-bb) method to do this after construction:

```
boost::circular_buffer<bool> stuff;
// ...

size_t BUFFER_SIZE(1024); // Whatever is appropriate
stuff.set_capacity(BUFFER_CAPACITY);
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I forgot to specify capacity for the buffer. It's annoying that Boost lets me get away with it, though.